# Flask scalability

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm working on a flask API and found that Flask has a very limited QPS. I tried different ways to solve this, like

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

which didn't work at all;

I also tried to use gunicorn with gevent, which works well under around 30 QPS, but not working with higher QPS.

I am trying to have an API to receive high volume web hooks and I'm not sure whether Flask can make this work or not. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Thou shalt not use the built-in development server in production. Read the docs section about [deployment](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/)!

Comment: Try using uwsgi and then increase the number of processes there in uwsgi config file. https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html